# How should I parse JSON data into a listview?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-listview

This is my code :

```
public void handleBlogResponse() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (mVideoData == null) {
        updateDisplayForError();
    }
    else {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://sql.gamedayxtra.com/api/Club/GetClubVideos/1");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("_response");
            for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
            {
               JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
               String id =jb.getString("$id");
               String clubvid = jb.getString("ClubVideoId");
               String clubid = jb.getString("ClubId");
               String title = jb.getString("Title");
               String thumb = jb.getString("ThumbURL");
               String video = jb.getString("VideoURL");
               String date = jb.getString("DataAdded");

              }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught!!", e);
        }
    }
}'
```

I don't know how to put these string into a list view.

Comment: Create object called for example `Video` Then create new one for each iteration in for loop and add object for example into `List<Video>`. Then in `onPostExecute()` update `ListAdapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This is one possible solution.

Comment: I suggest you to use a customized ArrayAdapter to display the information you want. You may want to create a whole new class so you can instantiate an object for each JSONObject you got there.

Comment: I am very new to JSON, how would I create an arrayadapter

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial,http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html . Very in depth guide to listviews and adapters